# How to get parent element height in my scenario?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get parent element's height in my directive.

I have something like

```
(function(window, angular) {
    var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.directive('testElem', [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template:'<a class="button"></a>',
                link: function(scope, element) {                        
                    var height = angular.element(element).parent().height();
                    console.log(height); 
                    //the height is 0 because not all item.description are   
                    //rendered
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
})(window, angular);
```

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.description}}
    </div>
    <a test-elem href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the height of `#container` AFTER I have all the `{{item.description}}` rendered in my page. My current codes will get me height of it's parent as soon as the doms are finished which has no item.description.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: so the directive loads before the description's are available? you will probably want to `resolve` your descriptions first, and inject them into your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `$timeout` to run after the items are rendered on the page:

```
(function(window, angular) {
    var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.directive('testElem', [
        function($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template:'<a class="button"></a>',
                link: function(scope, element) {   
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var height = angular.element(element).parent().height();
                        console.log(height); //height should be accurate
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
})(window, angular);
```

$timeout returns a promise, which is resolved when the delay has passed and the timeout function provided is executed.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 1):

in your directive is asynchronously compiled with the ng-repeat directive. You can set up a promise and resolve it.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$q', '$timeout',function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.myPromise = deferred.promise;

    $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve()
    });   
}])
.directive('testElem', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template:'<a class="button"></a>',
            link: function(scope, element) { 
                scope.myPromise.then(function(){
                    var height = element.parent()[0].offsetHeight;
                    console.log(height);
                });      
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Here is a working sample:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmebhhga/2/).